# jQuery delay with multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know you can do something like this:

```
$('#item').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn();
```

which will fade the element with the id of item out, then wait a second before fading it back in again. But is there a way to fade one item out and a different one back in with a delay inbetween. I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
$('#item1').fadeOut().delay(1000).('#item2').fadeIn();
```

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the callback function:

```
$("#item1").fadeOut( function()
{
  $("#item2")
          // Wait for 600 ms 
          .delay(600)
          // Fade in
          .fadeIn();
});
```

See the docu: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

> fadeIn( [ duration ], [ easing ], [ callback ] )
>
> duration  A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>
> easing  A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
>
> callback  A function to call once the animation is complete.

Comment: If the `duration` parameter is omitted, the default is 400 ms. That means `#item2` will fade in 400 ms later, not 1000 ms later as OP expects.

Comment: I added a sample delay of 600 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Fade the second element in within a callback, giving it the delay instead of the first element.

If you want the delay to count just as the first element begins to fade out, subtract the fading speed from the total delay:

```
// Assuming default fading speed of 400 ms
var speed = 400, delay = 1000;

$('#item1').fadeOut(speed, function() {
    $('#item2').delay(delay - speed).fadeIn(speed);
});
```

If you want the delay to count after the first element has finished animating, use the full delay value:

```
$('#item1').fadeOut(speed, function() {
    $('#item2').delay(delay).fadeIn(speed);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 setTimeout(function() {  $('#item1').fadeOut();}, 500);
 setTimeout(function() {  $('#item2').fadeIn(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: This will not wait for `#item1` to fade out before starting the timeout. You'd have to add the time for fadeOut (400ms I believe) to the setTimeout call.